# Is there any way to set bundle ID via xml for different platforms

Tags: actionscript-3

I have my project setup for Android as well as for iOS. The bundle ID for both the platforms are different. Is there any way to automate this. For creating IPA/APK, I have to manually go and change the bundle ID. I want something where I don't have to go and change the bundle ID every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Animate/Flash, creating another profile (top left of publish settings) changing the output SWF filename, will use another [swf name]-app.xml descriptor, where you can differentiate everything. So, when you change profile, most of AIR publishing data will be set for you with a different bundle id.